# I am getting jQuery Jtable error while fetching data from the python server

Tags: python, jtable, jquery-jtable

I have a jQuery Jtable in the front end and I am using python flask in my server.

I used python flask to fetch data from the MYSQL server which I can view in the JSON format in my browser but, unfortunately I couldn't able to make the JSON data into the Jtable.

My front end jQuery Jtable is

```
  $('#eventsummary').jtable({
    actions: {
      listAction: function (postData) {
        return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/backend/groupdata',
            type: 'GET',
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
              $dfd.resolve(data);
              console.log("loading ");
            },
          });
        });
      }
    },
    fields: {
      irs_type: {
        title: "Date & Time",
        list: true,
      }
    }
  });

  $('#eventsummary').jtable('load');
```

[and this is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sud3U.png)

I am also able to view my console.log code in the browser, with no error in the console.

Can someone please help me with this

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using python jsonify to add my json data to the front end Jtable.

```
for result in data:
     json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
return jsonify(
    {
        'Result': "OK",
        'Records': json_data,
    }
```

)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing is the standard jTable application error. Your listAction has passed the server response to jTable, so there is no communications error. 
When the json response does NOT contain Result = 'OK' it displays the application error dialog, and shows the json Message in the dialog.
The very fact that the error dialog appears means jTable is not seeing Result = 'OK' in your server response. Look for that first, if you are still stuck please post your json response. The dialog is blank because there is no error `message` or jTable can't see it.